# `The select command property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'` in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

What is lacking in my code? I watched every step of the tutorials.

I tried many times still end up in this error:

```
Private Sub Retrieve()
        ListView1.Items.Clear()

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblpayin"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

        Try
            con.Open()
            adapter.Fill(dt)

            For Each row In dt.Rows
                populate(row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7), row(8), row(9), row(10), row(11), row(12), row(13), row(14), row(15), row(16), row(17), row(18), row(19), row(20), row(21), row(22))
            Next
            dt.Rows.Clear()
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()

        End Try

    End Sub

Private Sub populate(ID As String, FN As String, MN As String, LN As String, AD As String, CN As String, MD As String, PC As String, AM As String, TE As String, M1 As String, M2 As String, M3 As String, M4 As String, M5 As String, M6 As String, M7 As String, M8 As String, M9 As String, M10 As String, M11 As String, M12 As String)

        Dim row As String() = New String() {ID, FN, MN, LN, AD, CN, MD, PC, AM, TE, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, M11, M12}
        Dim item As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)
        ListView1.Items.Add(item)

    End Sub
```

I want to load the data in the listview from MS access database

Comment: You are creating an `OleDbCommand` object and then calling `Fill` on `adapter`.  Where are you creating an association between `adapter` and `cmd`?

Comment: Given that the error message is telling you specifically that the `SelectCommand` property hasn't been set, what do you think you're supposed to do with that command containing a "SELECT" statement?  No examples on the web will tell you to do what you're doing, so read some examples and do what they actually tell you to do.

Comment: There's actually no point creating that command.  The data adapter constructor will accept a "SELECT" statement as an argument and create the command internally.  It will even accept a connection string and create a connection internally.  You should spend some time reading the documentation for the relevant classes.

Comment: Also next time instead of `row(1), row(2)`... just have another for loop with i = 1 to 22 and do `row(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep User Interface code separate from data access code. The Retrieve method has no idea where the data is going and the populate has no idea where the data came from.

Connections need to be closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks take care of this even if there is an error. Command object fall into this category too. You can include both in one Using block.

When you fill the ListView you don't want the screen to redraw after every row is added. That can be very slow if there are many rows. Adding the ListViewItems to a List(Of ListViewItem) and then adding them all at once with the .AddRange method enclosed in a .BeginUpdate... .EndUpdate will speed things up.

```
Private Function Retrieve() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblpayin", con)
            con.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub populate()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim dt = Retrieve()
    Dim lst As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim li As New ListViewItem({row(1).ToString, row(2).ToString, row(3).ToString, row(4).ToString, row(5).ToString, row(6).ToString, row(7).ToString, row(8).ToString, row(9).ToString, row(10).ToString, row(11).ToString, row(12).ToString, row(13).ToString, row(14).ToString, row(15).ToString, row(16).ToString, row(17).ToString, row(18).ToString, row(19).ToString, row(20).ToString, row(21).ToString, row(22).ToString})
        lst.Add(li)
    Next
    dt.Dispose()
    ListView1.BeginUpdate()
    ListView1.Items.AddRange(lst.ToArray)
    ListView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Comment: You can even use `Using` on the DataTable: `Using dt As DataTable = Retrieve()`